# Local Existence for Heat equation with Lipschitz nonlinearity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, contraction-operator

Let's say we have $x\in [0,1]$ and we have the heat equation

$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t) = \Delta u(x,t) + f(u)$$ with $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$ and $u(x,0)\in L^2$. $f$ is lipschitz continuous. I want to show local existence of the weak solution in $L^2$.

Here's what I did:
$$u(x,t) = S(t)u_0 + \int_0^t S(t-s)f(u)ds$$

is the weak solution where $S(t)$ is the heat semigroup $(u_0 = u(x,0))$.

Define $$\mathcal{K}(v):= S(t)v_0 + \int_0^t S(t-s)f(v)ds$$

Then for $v, w\in L^2$ with $v_0 = w_0$ we consider

\begin{align}
\sup_{t\in [0,T]}\left\| \mathcal{K}v - \mathcal{K}w \right\|_2 &= \sup_{t\in [0,T]}\left\|\int_0^T S(t-s)[f(v)-f(w)]\,ds\right\|_2\\
&\leq \sup_{t\in [0,T]}\int_0^T\left\|S(t-s)[f(v)-f(w)]\right\|_2\,ds\\
&\leq \sup_{t\in [0,T]}\int_0^T e^{-\omega_1(t-s)}C\left\|v-w\right\|_2 \,ds\\
&\leq T*1*C*\sup_{t\in [0,T]}\left\|v-w\right\|_2.
\end{align}

In the last two steps, $C$ is the Lipschitz constant for $f$ and $\omega_1$ is the principal eigenvalue of the Laplace operator.

Pick $T$ small enough and we have a contraction mapping, so that implies the existence of a local solution.  Does this argument work? Can I tweak it slightly to also work for $f$ locally Lipschitz?  I was thinking for the locally Lipschitz case of maybe considering the ball in $L^2$ of radius $M$, and only choosing $v$ and $w$ in that ball.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the property of $S(t)$ that you are using (the one with the principal eigenvalue). But I guess you are probably right. Alternatively you could use the fact that the space integral of $S(t)$ is smaller than 1 for any $t>0$ which basically leads to the same result.

Comment: Moreover, your idea for the locally Lipschitz case is good. For locally Lipschitz you only get existence up to a time $T>0$ whereas in the Lipschitz case you get existence for all time.

Comment: @SC2020 Sorry for the late reply, I just saw your comments today.  the principal eigenvalue property comes from the fact that the solution to the heat equation over the [0,1] interval is given by $S(t)f = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}e^{-\omega_k t}\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k$ where $e_k$ are eigenfunctions of the laplacian with corresponding eigenvalues $\omega_k$.

Comment: @SC2020 I'm still trying to work out the details of the locally Lipschitz case.  For example, I don't see how bounding it in an $L^2$ ball of radius $M$ helps.  For example if $f = u^3$,  the integral becomes $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\int_0^Te^{-\omega_1t}\|v^3-w^3\|_2$ but locally lipschitz does not allow me to conclude anything about a bound in $L^2$.  For example, I dont' think I can say that $\|f(v)-f(w)\|_2 \leq C_M\|v-w\|_2$ for $v,w$ in a ball of radius $M$. But it would've worked if the norm was the sup norm instead of the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: One way to bypass this is problem is by assuming that, as you suggested, $u_0$ is bounded, i.e., $u_0 \in L^\infty$. You can then show existence of a local weak solution in $L^\infty$. This is what I initially had in mind. But I admit that if you are set on working in $L^2$ then it is more complicated and you might need more assumptions on $f$ otherwise the problem might even be ill-posed. Do you have a specific example in mind, like $f=u^3$ in space dimension $n=1$ or are you interested in just a general locally Lipschitz function?

Comment: @SC2020 In fact, $f=u^3$ is exactly the example I had in mind! I was considering truncating it with $f_n = u^3\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}$ and showing that the solutions converge to the solution with $f$ using dct.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work since for each $f_n$ you get existence up to a $T_n$ with $T_n \geq T_{n+1}$. If you want to get a useful result from dct you need to show something like $T_n \geq \epsilon > 0$ for all $n$. Which basically boils down to the same problem as above.

Comment: But I will try to answer your question as soon as I'll find the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We denote by $e^{t\Delta}f$ the convolution of $f$ with the heat kernel. As an example the heat Kernel in $\mathbb{R}$ is given by $$\Phi_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-x^2/(4t)}$$ (a.k.a. the fundamental solution of the heat equation). If you take the Green's $G$ function for your problem (basically the fundamental solution with boundary conditions $G(0,t)=0=G(1,t)$) then this is your heat kernel for this problem. And $e^{t\Delta}f$ is just the convolution of $G$ with $f$ in $x$. What I want to say is that $e^{t\Delta}$ is your heat semigroup $S(t)$.

This heat semigroup has the following important property:

$$||e^{t\Delta} \phi||_q \leq  (4\pi t)^{\frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}\right)} ||\phi||_p.$$

We are going to use this and the general Hölder inequality $$||fg||_r \leq ||f||_p ||g||_q,$$ where $1/r = 1/p + 1/q$ to construct a fixed-point argument in the following Banach space

$$X_\tau := \{u \in L^\infty((0,\tau);L^6([0,1]) : ||u||_\tau < \infty \},$$

where $$||u||_\tau := \sup_{0<t<\tau} t^{1/6} ||u(t)||_6.$$

Next we choose $M > ||u_0||_2$ and we denote by $B_{M,\tau}$ the closed ball in $X_\tau$ with center $0$ and radius $M$. We apply the fixed point argument to the following mapping $$S(v)(t) := e^{t\Delta}u_0 + \int_0^t e^{(t-s)\Delta}u^3(s) ds.$$

So let $u,v \in B_{M,\tau}$ we get
\begin{align*}
t^{1/6}||S(u)(t)-S(v)(t)||_6 &\leq t^{1/6} \int_0^t \left|\left|e^{(t-s)\Delta}\left(u^3(s)-v^3(s)\right)\right|\right|_6 ds
\\
&\leq t^{1/6} \int_0^t (t-s)^{-1/6} \left|\left|u^3(s)-v^3(s)\right|\right|_2 ds,
\end{align*}
where we used the heat semigroup property. We estimate the norm term separately
\begin{align*}
\left|\left|u^3-v^3\right|\right|_2 &= \frac{1}{2} ||(u-v)(u^2+v^2)+(u+v)(u^2-v^2)||_2
\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \left(||u-v||_6 \left(||u^2||_3+||v^2||_3\right) + \left(||u||_6+||v||_6\right)||u^2-v^2||_3\right)
\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \left(||u-v||_6 \left(||u^2||_3+||v^2||_3\right) + \left(||u||_6+||v||_6\right)||(u-v)(u+v)||_3\right)
\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \left(||u-v||_6 \left(||u^2||_3+||v^2||_3\right) + \left(||u||_6+||v||_6\right)\left(||u||_6+||v||_6\right)||u-v||_6\right)
\\
&\leq C \left(||u||_6^2 + ||v||_6^2\right) ||u-v||_6
\end{align*}

where we used Hölder's inequality and the triangel inequality a couple of times.

Putting everything together we get \begin{align*}
t^{1/6}||S(u)(t)-S(v)(t)||_6 &\leq C t^{1/6} \int_0^t (t-s)^{-1/6} \left(||u||_6^2 + ||v||_6^2\right) ||u-v||_6  ds
\\
&\leq C M^2 t^{1/6} \int_0^t (t-s)^{-1/6} s^{-2/6} ||u-v||_6  ds
\\
&\leq C M^2 t^{1/6} \int_0^t (t-s)^{-1/6} s^{-1/2} ds \, \, ||u-v||_\tau
\\
&\leq C M^2 \int_0^t s^{-1/2} ds \, \, ||u-v||_\tau
\\
&\leq C M^2 \sqrt{t}  ||u-v||_\tau
\\
&\leq C M^2 \sqrt{\tau} ||u-v||_\tau
\end{align*}

Note if we choose $\tau>0$ small enough,i.e., such that $CM^2 \sqrt{\tau} <1/2$, then we have a contraction mapping.

Next we look at the norm of $S(u)$

\begin{align*}
t^{1/6} ||S(u)(t)||_6 &\leq t^{1/6} ||e^{t\Delta}u_0||_6 + CM^3\sqrt{\tau}
\\
&\leq (4\pi)^{-1/6} ||u_0||_2 + CM^3\sqrt{\tau},
\end{align*}

where we used the heat semigropu property in the first term and the result from the difference estimate with $v=0$ for the second term. Note that $(4\pi)^{-1/6} < 1$, hence, we can choose $\tau$ small enough such that we have $$||S(v)||_\tau < M.$$

So $S$ is indeed a contraction mapping from $B_{M,\tau}$ to $B_{M,\tau}$. Thus, Banach's fixed-point theorem asserts the existence of unique integral solution in $B_{M,\tau}$.

Note that we have shown that $u(t) \in L^6$, therefore, $f(u) = u^3(t) \in L^2$. Since our unique fixed point satisfies $$u(t) = e^{t\Delta}u_0 + \int_0^t e^{(t-s)\Delta}f(u)(s) ds,$$ and using the smoothing properties of $e^{t\Delta}$, you should be able show that $u(t) \in L^2$ by using a bootstrap type argument.

Comment: Thanks so much for this write up! That's an interesting idea with changing the banach space to something more helpful like with norm $t^{1/6}\|\cdot\|_6$.  Is this a standard technique somewhere? Also where do you get the heatsemigroup bound of $(t-s)^{1/2-1/3}$? Seems like it's a standard result but I haven't seen it before.  Is that ultracontractivity perhaps?

Comment: @iYOA I don't know if this is a general technique but as far as I know it is the standard approach for this type of equation. Maybe compare Weissler's papers "Local Existence and Nonexistence for Semilinear Parabolic Equations in $L^p$" & "Semilinear Evolution Equations in Banach Spaces".

Comment: @iYOA This property might be called ultracontractivity in some settings. I just know it as the smoothing property of the heat semigroup. For proving it, you show that it holds for the cases $p=q$ and $p=1, q=\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The other cases you get by using the Riesz-Thorin Interpolation Theorem. For the interval $[0,1]$ you use the maximum principle for the heat equation.

Comment: @iYOA in my experience it is hard to find good books for this type of problem but maybe you can look at the book "Superlinear Parabolic Problems" by Quittner-Souplet. Some sections might be useful.